# ProFTPd won't allow me to log in after password change

Tags: ftp, pam, ubuntu-14.04

I've changed a password for one of my users (using `passwd username`), and now ProFTPd won't allow that user to log in. Other users can still log in as normal.

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

The error I'm getting in /var/log/auth.log is:

```
pam_unix(proftpd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=/dev/ftpd28150 ruser=webuser rhost=188-39-142-115.static.enta.net  user=webuser
```

The user (as per /etc/passwd) remains the same as the other FTP users which still work:

```
webuser:x:1001:1001::/var/www/thewebsite.co.uk:
```

Is there somewhere else that PAM looks to authenticate the user?

**EDIT**

My /etc/proftpd doesn't contain a .htaccess, it just contains the following:

```
blacklist.dat
conf.d
dhparams.pem
ldap.conf
modules.conf
proftpd.conf
sql.conf
tls.conf
virtuals.conf
```

My proftpd.conf looks like this:

```
Include /etc/proftpd/modules.conf
UseIPv6                         on
IdentLookups                    off
ServerName                      "Debian"
ServerType                      standalone
DeferWelcome                    off
MultilineRFC2228                on
DefaultServer                   on
ShowSymlinks                    on
TimeoutNoTransfer               600
TimeoutStalled                  600
TimeoutIdle                     1200
DisplayLogin                    welcome.msg
DisplayChdir                    .message true
ListOptions                     "-l"
DenyFilter                      \*.*/
Port                            21
MaxInstances                    30
User                            proftpd
Group                           nogroup
Umask                           022  022
AllowOverwrite                  on
# PersistentPasswd              off
# AuthOrder                     mod_auth_pam.c* mod_auth_unix.c
# UseSendFile                   off
TransferLog /var/log/proftpd/xferlog
SystemLog   /var/log/proftpd/proftpd.log

<IfModule mod_quotatab.c>
QuotaEngine off
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_ratio.c>
Ratios off
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_delay.c>
DelayEngine on
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_ctrls.c>
ControlsEngine        off
ControlsMaxClients    2
ControlsLog           /var/log/proftpd/controls.log
ControlsInterval      5
ControlsSocket        /var/run/proftpd/proftpd.sock
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_ctrls_admin.c>
AdminControlsEngine off
</IfModule>
```

Comment: please provide configuration and more information

Comment: It could be that your server is configured to use a `.htpasswd` file for authentication, look for such a file in `/etc/proftpd`, these files usually have 600 permissions (rw-------).

Comment: Updated my question for both of you guys...

Comment: Theres no shell listed in the users passwd entry. I'm not sure if not setting it is valid.

Comment: That's not making a difference - other FTP users don't have a shell and they work. It was simply the action of changing the user's password that's caused this issue to arise.

Comment: Your posted `proftpd.conf` has the `AuthOrder` directive, but that one is commented out.  Do any of the other `.conf` files you mentioned have an `AuthOrder` directive in them?